# Dealing with commands in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to handle a command. In my simple application I have a `textbox` named `txtEditor`. In the code there is a problem that I do not know why it happens.
Whenever I run the following code, it executes well.

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (txtEditor != null)
        e.CanExecute = (txtEditor.Text != null) && (txtEditor.SelectionLength > 0);
}
```

But for the following code:

```
private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    e.CanExecute = (txtEditor.Text != null) && (txtEditor.SelectionLength > 0);
}
```

I get this Error:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

I have bound the command to the `CommandBindings` of `Window` Collection. 
The problem is that I do not know the reason why this error happens, if `txtEditor` is not initialized, so what does method `InitializeComponent()` do in the constructor of `WPF` window?

And also When are the commands called that this error happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `CanExecute` event is fired independently from your window intialization whenever [CommandManager.RequerySuggested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx) event is triggered. That's why it is not guaranteed that it will be fired after `InitializedComponent()` is called.

You can easily check this by handling your windows' `Initialized` event:

```
private void MainWindow_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("MainWindow initialized");
}

private void CutCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CommandBinding_CanExecute fired");
}
```

By doing so you will notice that `CanExecute` is fired before your window is actually initialized and in the output window you will see:

```
CommandBinding_CanExecute fired
MainWindow initialized
CommandBinding_CanExecute fired
CommandBinding_CanExecute fired
```

Answer (score 0):

Before `InitializeComponent()` is called, `txtEditor` is null. Inside this method all the UI elements gets initialized:

```
this.txtEditor = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)(target));
```

After the call it will not be null, it will be `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`. You are trying to access an object which is referring to null.